# How to convert simple CSS grid into Flexbox version without strange effect

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to get a page layout similar to https://material.angular.io. I used angular/flex-layout to create a combined flexbox/grid layout that works pretty much as intended. The innermost containers (navigation and content) were placed inside a CSS grid, but since it was basically only used as a 2-dimensional container, I thought I could easily replace that one with a column-flexbox. But only that results in this strange effect when scrolling down:

[image]

- [Flexbox (buggy) version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-io-behavior-no-css-grid?file=app%2Fsub-content%2Fsub-content.component.html)
- [CSS Grid version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-io-behavior-grid-version?file=app/sub-content/sub-content.component.html)

The navigation box on the left should behave sticky and not get pushed below the title toolbar.

Is it possible to only use flexbox for this kind of layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of angular/flex-layout attributes were misconfigured along with some CSS styles. I started again and managed to create a version that behaves the same for CSS Grid and Flexbox:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-io-behavior-with-bootstrap

There's a button in the second toolbar that lets you switch between the CSS grid and the flexbox version on the fly.